# Selecting parts of 2d array based on x value

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a 2d array such as `x={{1,2},{2,3},{3,4},{4,5},{5,6}}` how would I extract all pairs where the first value is between 2 and 4 such that `xpart={{2,3},{3,4},{4,5}}`? I need to do this for a very large data set based on different x value constraints, 2 and 4 are just simplified expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}}
x // Select[Between[First@#, {2, 4}] &]

(* {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}};
```

Some alternatives

Using `Cases`

```
Cases[list, {2 | 3 | 4, _}]
```

{{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Catenate @ SequenceSplit[list, {{a_, _}} /; ! Between[a, {2, 4}]]
```

{{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}

Using `ReplaceAll`

```
list /. {a_, _} /; ! Between[a, {2, 4}] :> Nothing
```

{{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}

Using `Delete`

```
p = Position[list, {a_, _} /; a < 2 || a > 4]
```

{{1}, {5}}

```
Delete[p] @ list
```

{{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}

Answer (score 1):

```
x = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}};
```

---

Using `Replace` at level `1`:

```
Replace[x, {a_ /; ! Between[a, {2, 4}], _} :> Nothing, {1}]

(*{{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}*)
```

Or using `ReplaceList`:

```
ReplaceList[x, {___, s : {a_ /; Between[a, {2, 4}], _}, ___} :> s]

(*{{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}*)
```